# Use of Application.DoEvents relating to WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, winforms

I have inherited an application that makes use of a WebBrowser control to display PDF files.  Many times throughout the code the application calls the Application.DoEvents method, usually after calling the Navigate function and setting the Url property of the WebBrowser control (sets both to null, as to clear the page).  I'm not sure why this was done but I think it's causing crashes according to logs.

This function is also used when updating progress bar and setting labels but this is done in a loop so I can see what purpose it would serve.

Can someone explain why this would be done?  I know that this function has use inside a loop but outside a loop I don't understand its purpose.  Here's two samples of the code I'm talking about:

```
private void txtBoxFile_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   browser.Navigate("");
   browser.Url = null;
   Application.DoEvents();
}
```

and

```
private UpdateMessage(int timePassed)
{
   progressBar.Value = (int)Math.Min(timePassed, progressBar.Maximum);
   label.Text = timePassed.ToString() + " seconds have elapsed.";
   Application.DoEvents();
}
```

What possible side effects could there be if I were to comment out all the calls in one sweep?  There isn't much processing time involved with the application as is, so even UI delay is not a concern.

Comment: Possible side effect is that bad coding elsewhere expects the side effecting behavior of DoEvents.  That said, I certainly support getting rid of those calls as they are more than likely causing your issues and do not serve a valid purpose in the examples you gave.

Comment: The programmer that wrote that probably figured out a long time ago that calling DoEvents can make the DocumentCompleted event fire and solve a deadlock.  So he sprinkled them in his code to make it work 'better'.  At least putting them at the end of an event handler isn't fatal.  Every other usage is an accident waiting to happen.